# What is the appropiate sintaxis to create App and Router on Embers pre-1.0?

Tags: ember.js

I´m starting to code a simple app for testing Router in Ember pre-1.0.
So far I´ve put code based on official documentation (http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Router.html). It seems to have change the syntaxis for the routes. My question is. what is the appropiate sintaxis to create the App and the Router?

I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined"

Comment: Can you show your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: There's Router Beginner Guide that works well with latest API at https://github.com/sgharms/website/blob/5ea08477ff790834396a46a4519259f6f54aa52f/source/guides/router_primer.md . Try it

Comment: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/besign/QFa7t/. You can see the errors in Console
Is the proper way to instanciate the Router: 

Router: Ember.Router.extend({...})

or

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({...})

Comment: See update http://jsfiddle.net/QFa7t/2/. Your mistake was you didn't include jQuery. I also added application template

Comment: To iterate a bit, http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/QFa7t/4/ breaks the definitions out of the Ember.Application.create({...}) call, which you'd probably want to do, and http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/QFa7t/5/ adds an outlet and connects another controller + view to it.

Comment: Thanks! I got really confused with the documentation, but this was exactly my doubt. I wanted to keep the definitions out of the creation of the App.